# memory issue: realtime eye localization

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm currently working on a iOS-application, which should be able to detect the localization. I've created an tflite which comprises some CNN layers. In order to use the tflite in XCode/Swift I've created a helper class in which the tflite calculates the output. Whenever I run the predict-function once, it works. But apparently the predict function doesn't work in real-time camera-thread.

After about 7 seconds, XCode is throwing the following error:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x123424001)`. This error must be evoken by looping through the image. Since I need each pixel value I'm using the solution suggested by [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/use-custom-models).But apparently this solution is not waterproofed. Can anybody help to resolve this memory issue?

```
func creatInputForCNN(resizedImage: UIImage?) -> Data{
// In this section of the code I loop through the image (150,200,3) 
// in order to fetch each pixel value (RGB).


    let image: CGImage = resizedImage.cgImage!
    
    guard let context = CGContext(
        data: nil,
        width: image.width, height: image.height,
        bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: image.width * 4,
        space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue
    ) else {return nil}
    context.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.width, height: image.height))
    guard let imageData = context.data else {return nil}
    
    
    let size_w = 150
    let size_H = 200
    
    var inputData:Data?
    inputData = Data()
    
    for row in 0 ..< size_H{
    for col in 0 ..< size_w {
    let offset = 4 * (row * context.width + col)
    // (Ignore offset 0, the unused alpha channel)
    let red = imageData.load(fromByteOffset: offset+1, as: UInt8.self)
    let green = imageData.load(fromByteOffset: offset+2, as: UInt8.self)
    let blue = imageData.load(fromByteOffset: offset+3, as: UInt8.self)
    
    // Normalize channel values to [0.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies
    // by model. For example, some models might require values to be
    // normalized to the range [-1.0, 1.0] instead, and others might
    // require fixed-point values or the original bytes.
    
    
    var normalizedRed:Float32 = Float32(red) / 255
    var normalizedGreen:Float32 = (Float32(green) / 255
    var normalizedBlue:Float32 = Float32(blue) / 255
    
    
    
    // Append normalized values to Data object in RGB order.
    let elementSize = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: normalizedRed)
    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: elementSize)
    memcpy(&bytes, &normalizedRed, elementSize)
    inputData!.append(&bytes, count: elementSize)
    memcpy(&bytes, &normalizedGreen, elementSize)
    inputData!.append(&bytes, count: elementSize)
    memcpy(&bytes, &normalizedBlue, elementSize)
    inputData!.append(&bytes, count: elementSize)


    return inputData
}
```

This is the code

Comment: A couple of things. This really doesn't appear to be Firebase related - the issue is with your Swift code. Secondly the code is not formatted and hard to read. Take a moment and use the code formatting tools to edit the question. Generally, if you simply use command-[ in xcode to scoot it all the way to the left, copy and paste it here, select it, and then use the format {} button, it kinda takes care of that for you. Please update the question.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for mention it. I've updated my code in order to be more readable. I definitely agree that this issue isn't related with Firebase. But since I have the code snippets from there, I thought it would be the most efficient way to do it. Can you help to resolve my issue?

Comment: Is this `row * context.width + col` correct based on order of operations? Either way, stepping through your code and identifying the line that's crashing is a requirement here on SO, so we don't have to guess at where the issue lies.

Comment: @Jay Sorry for not having provided this information. The error appears on the line `imageData.load(fromByteOffset: offset+1, as: UInt8.self)`. The code snippets `row * context.width + col` is a mystery to my self. Since it was suggested by Firebase I haven't double checked it yet.

Comment: Well, first step in troubleshooting is to step through you code, inspecting your variables to see where they go wrong. `row * context.width + col` is totally different than `row * (context.width + col)`.